# Can you compile and execute Java files in Geany with one command?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, geany

Is there a way to compile and execute java files using one command, say <kbd>F1</kbd>, in Geany?

Its much more comfortable than having to click f5 to wait for the class to compile first, then <kbd>F1</kbd> to execute that compiled file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a shell script that first compiles the class and then runs it. Then set up this shell script instead of pointing Geany to `javac` and `java` respectively.

On the downside, you will have to handle compilation failures in the script, which sounds ugly.

I would recommend to stick with the existing workflow in Geany.

If you're looking for advanced functionality, you might want to consider upgrading to a real IDE like *Eclipse* or *Netbeans*.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can!

While editing a Java file, go to *Build > Set Build Commands*. Under *Java commands* click the first empty label and give it a name, e.g. `Compile & Execute`. Then in the *Command* field enter the command line you would use in a terminal to compile and execute your files, substituting file and class names with variables (see the [Geany manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#substitutions-in-commands-and-working-directories)).

For example, on Linux one would use `javac "%f" && java "%e"`. (Using && ensures the resulting class file is only executed when compilation is succesful.)

Click OK and open the *Build* menu again to see the *Compile & Execute* command is now there. In my case Geany automatically assigned it the shortcut key <kbd>F9</kbd>. If there's no shortcut key you can assign one in *Preferences > Keybindings*.

Pressing your shortcut key will now run the command line you entered and display its output in the *Compiler* tab of the *Message Window.* Alternatively you can create your build command under *Execute commands* instead of *Java commands*, and it will be run in a terminal window instead.

Comment: Good. Is it possible to pass a class or should I write after `javac` the classpath?